# use ExtendedPropTypes with styleguidelist

Tags: react-styleguidist

i am not able to use **[ExtendedPropTypes](https://github.com/peterkhayes/extended-proptypes)** with **styleguidelist**

getting error

./app/components/Common/Error/ErrorBoundary.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'extended-proptypes' in '/app/components/Common/Error'